# How to solve "node_modules are empty"?

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

While using `ng serve` on my *local*, the error is

> node_modules are empty.

Already checked with `npm install -g @angular/cli`, 
i think there is some issue with my installation for *node*, *npm*, or *angular-cli*.

But i could not get the proper reason.

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: yes, but not solved the problem

Comment: Do you have a sub directory `node_modules` in your project? Is it empty?

Comment: Yes its empty but there is cli folder too.

Comment: Is there a `package.json` file in your project? Then run `npm install`.

Comment: Yes there is. and also run npm install.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Check out my answer here, should fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/49417358/7893665