# What could cause an error related to npm not being able to find a file? No contents in my node_modules subfolder. Why is that?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to run `npm install` in the angular project folder I got from [ASP.NET Boilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template-Angular) and I'm getting an error that is "related to npm not being able to find a file."

```
D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular>npm install
npm WARN deprecated @types/moment@2.13.0: This is a stub types definition for Moment (https://github.com/moment/moment). Moment provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/moment installed!
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-8cc0601e\node_modules\are-we-there-yet' -> 'D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular\node_modules\.staging\are-we-there-yet-cedb4a6a'

npm ERR! path D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript' -> 'D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\.typescript.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-21T19_33_18_250Z-debug.log
```

I can clearly see that this is happening because my `node_modules` subfolder contains only a single folder structure with no files within it. That structure is:

```
node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules
```

I have node 8.9.4, npm 5.6.0, and angular-CLI 1.5.0 installed as well as typescript 2.0.0. The latter two packages have been installed globally.

Here are the `package.json` file contents:

```
{
    "name": "MyProject",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "angular-cli": {},
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200",
        "hmr": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 4201 --hmr -e=hmr",
        "test": "ng test",
        "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
        "e2e": "protractor"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/common": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/http": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.3",
        "@angular/router": "^5.0.3",
        "@aspnet/signalr": "1.0.0-preview1-28189",
        "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.33",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
        "@types/jquery.blockui": "0.0.28",
        "@types/jquery.validation": "^1.16.3",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.62",
        "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
        "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.34",
        "@types/signalr": "^2.2.33",
        "@types/toastr": "^2.1.33",
        "abp-ng2-module": "^1.3.0",
        "abp-web-resources": "^3.3.0",
        "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
        "block-ui": "^2.70.1",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.2",
        "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "famfamfam-flags": "^1.0.0",
        "flot": "^0.8.0-alpha",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.1.1",
        "jquery-countto": "^1.2.0",
        "jquery-migrate": "^3.0.0",
        "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
        "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
        "js-cookie": "^2.1.4",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "moment": "^2.18.1",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
        "morris.js": "^0.5.0",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
        "ngx-pagination": "^3.0.3",
        "node-waves": "^0.7.5",
        "push.js": "1.0.4",
        "raphael": "^2.2.7",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
        "signalr": "^2.2.1",
        "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
        "spin.js": "^2.3.2",
        "sweetalert": "^2.0.8",
        "toastr": "^2.1.2",
        "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
        "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
        "zone.js": "0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.5.4",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.3",
        "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
        "@types/node": "^8.0.27",
        "codelyzer": "^3.1.2",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
        "karma": "^1.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "nswag": "^11.12.7",
        "protractor": "^5.1.1",
        "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
        "tslint": "^5.7.0",
        "typescript": "2.4.2"
    }
}
```

When I run `npm install`, I can see the packages being downloaded into the `.staging` folder. At the point that the `finalize` command is run (see the log below), I can see that the package folders are being consolidated and copied somewhere, but that somewhere does not appear to be my `node_modules` subfolder other than the first set of subfolders as I have shown above. When the `npm install` completes, the `.staging` folder is deleted and all that I have left is that partial folder structure.

Admittedly I am new to Node development - I usually work on our ASP.NET Web API backends. I'm trying to get my development environment in sync with our front-end developer's development environment. I have spent most of the day looking for a solution. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Node. I've tried different versions that match our front-end developer's environment. I've tried using the latest versions of angular-CLI and typescript and have fallen back to the versions I reference above in hopes that the "requires a peer" warnings would be resolved. I have searched for similar answers on this site. [The closest one I have found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201493/how-to-solve-node-modules-are-empty) remains unanswered.

Here is the end of the "complete log" referenced in the npm error output:

```
19577 silly saveTree | `-- tsutils@2.22.2
19577 silly saveTree +-- typescript@2.4.2
19577 silly saveTree +-- web-animations-js@2.3.1
19577 silly saveTree `-- zone.js@0.8.18
19578 warn codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
19579 warn codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
19580 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
19581 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-8cc0601e\node_modules\are-we-there-yet' -> 'D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular\node_modules\.staging\are-we-there-yet-cedb4a6a'
19582 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
19582 verbose optional Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
19583 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript' -> 'D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\.typescript.DELETE'
19584 verbose cwd D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular
19585 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
19586 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
19587 verbose node v8.9.4
19588 verbose npm  v5.6.0
19589 error path D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript
19590 error code ENOENT
19591 error errno -4058
19592 error syscall rename
19593 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript' -> 'D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\.typescript.DELETE'
19594 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
19595 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

Please advise.

Comment: Delete node_modules folder manually, then install the latest node.js, then run yarn from the Angular folder. It will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you @viveknuna. Once I upgraded the node.js, npm, angular-cli, and typescript and then installed yarn. I was able to run `yarn` successfully and then I was able to run `npm start`successfully. What exactly did that do? That is – what should I learn from your suggestion?

Comment: @viveknuna, I was wondering though why the `yarn` command worked when the `npm install` command did not. Is there any insight you can share with me?

Comment: updated my answer, please check.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It might be related to corruption in Angular Packages or incompatibility of packages.

Please follow the below steps to solve the issue.

- Delete node_modules folder manually.
- Install Node ( https://nodejs.org/en/download ).
- Install Yarn ( https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install ).
- Open command prompt , go to path angular folder and run Yarn.
- Run angular\nswag\refresh.bat.
- Run npm start from the angular folder.

**Update**

ASP.NET Boilerplate suggests [here](https://aspnetzero.com/Documents/Getting-Started-Angular) to use yarn because npm has some problems. It is slow and can not consistently resolve dependencies, yarn solves those problems and it is compatible to npm as well.

Comment: Although I used the procedure detailed in my answer below to actually fix my problem, @viveknuna provided the suggestions I needed to get the project working so I am accepting his answer "because it solved [my] problem [and] was most helpful in finding [my] solution".

Comment: @jlavallet that’s why I upvoted your answer buddy :) happy coding.

Comment: so the solution is to switch to yarn ;P

Answer (score 81):

The following steps work for me:

1. **`npm cache clean -f`**
2. `rm -rf node_modules`
3. `npm i`

Answer (score 6):

Try the following steps:
1. Make sure you have the latest npm (npm install -g npm).
2. Add an exception to your antivirus to ignore the node_modules folder in your project.
3. $ rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json .
4. $ npm install

Answer (score 4):

I had the SAME issue today and it was driving me nuts!!! What I had done was upgrade to node 8.10 and upgrade my NPM to the latest I uninstalled angular CLI

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
```

I then verified my Cache from NPM if it wasn't up to date I cleaned it and ran the install again
if npm version is < 5 then use `npm cache clean --force`

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

and created a new project file and create a new angular project.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution did not seem to fix my problem. I followed it to the point of creating a new project file and a new angular project. Maybe that was key but during the run of the `npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli`  command it appeared to be doing exactly the same things as before. This surprised me because I thought all I was doing was uninstalling angular-cli. As I said in my post though – I am new to Node.js development so I may have missed something fundamental. Also, as I said in my post – I tried to run `npm install` with the latest versions of everything without success.

Answer (score 4):

In my case

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Also not working so, I use

> yarn

First, install yarn globally

```
npm i -g yarn
```

Then instead of "npm start", I do,

```
yarn add
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Following what @viveknuna suggested, I upgraded to the latest version of node.js and npm using the downloaded installer. I also installed the latest version of yarn using a downloaded installer. Then, as you can see below, I upgraded angular-cli and typescript. Here's what that process looked like:

```
D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular>npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cli@1.7.3
added 75 packages, removed 166 packages, updated 61 packages and moved 24 packages in 29.084s

D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular>npm install -g typescript
C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsserver -> C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc -> C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
+ typescript@2.7.2
updated 1 package in 2.427s

D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular>node -v
v8.10.0

D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular>npm -v
5.6.0

D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular>yarn --version
1.5.1
```

Thereafter, I ran `yarn` and `npm start` in my angular folder and all appears to be well. Here's what that looked like:

```
D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular>yarn
yarn install v1.5.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "@angular/cli > @schematics/angular@0.1.10" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.40".
warning "@angular/cli > @angular-devkit/schematics > @schematics/schematics@0.0.10" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.40".
warning " > codelyzer@3.2.2" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0".
warning " > codelyzer@3.2.2" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 232.79s.

D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular>npm start

> MyProject@0.0.0 start D:\Dev\AspNetBoilerplate\MyProject\3.5.0\angular
> ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200

** NG Live Development Server is listening on 0.0.0.0:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2018-03-22T13:17:28.935Z
Hash: 8f226b6fa069b7c201ea
Time: 22494ms
chunk {account.module} account.module.chunk.js () 129 kB  [rendered]
chunk {app.module} app.module.chunk.js () 497 kB  [rendered]
chunk {common} common.chunk.js (common) 1.46 MB  [rendered]
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 5.79 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 515 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 1.1 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 1.53 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 15.1 MB [initial] [rendered]

webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Comment: Good, it will help others :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too. It was resolved by realising that I was running the command in the wrong folder. `pwd` to check the folder. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error happened with a new project.

none of the proposed solutions here worked, so I simply reinstalled all the packages and started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried to run `npm i firebase@7.8.2` and got the error because the dev server was running in another terminal on vsc. Hit ctrl+c, y to stop it in that terminal, and then installation works.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens, then it means you have to upgrade your node.js. Simply uninstall your current node from your pc or mac and download the latest version from https://nodejs.org/en/

Answer (score 0):

Change your `firebase.json` from:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

To:

```
{
  "functions": {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do it in a folder inside dropbox. I think dropbox was locking files as it uploaded them or something and that didn't work. It would fail in different places.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are running the npm command in the right directory

```
cd directory_name and run?
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had to create a new app, reinstall my node packages, and copy my src document over.  That worked.