# No such file cli.js in angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to create my first angular app and While creating a new project using command '**ng new my-app**' i am getting error like - 
*No such file cli.js
This is related to npm not being able to find the file.*
[Image - cli.js not found while creating angular app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwsQa.png)

[image]

I tried various steps including changing the PATH env variable to point to the npm installation folder, but still the same issue.
Also, while using a Seed project from Github and issuing command - npm install , again i get the same error.
I am using node version 8.11.3. and following the steps given in https://angular.io/guide/quickstart#devenv

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Could you provide full error message?

Comment: Hi Aleander, now i have provided a link of the  error image

Comment: Please provide all the steps you took. What command did you use to install the @ngular/cli? It looks like the cli is trying to run from a local node_modules dir rather than global.

Comment: To install angular  i have used  -  npm install -g @angular/cli.

Comment: try to install build optimizer locally: `npm i @angular-devkit/build-optimizer -D` or globally: `npm i @angular-devkit/build-optimizer -g`

Comment: @Andriy  I get the same error

Comment: This was finally solved by installing yarn.  The project finally compiled successfully. Seems the issue was with the current  node version installation itself. I thank everyone who replied to this post.   I followed the steps mentioned  in  below link  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415958/what-could-cause-an-error-related-to-npm-not-being-able-to-find-a-file-no-conte