# I cant create a react app its keeps giving me an error

Tags: npm, create-react-app

when I am running "npx create react app react20 " it giving me below error

I have been trying for more than 12 hours to fix this and I cant figure it our. I dont know what to do next guys/gals please help.

```html
PS C:\Users\Imran\Desktop\zertomastery\20_react> npx create-react-app react20

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Imran\Desktop\zertomastery\20_react\react20.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Imran\Desktop\zertomastery\20_react\react20\node_modules\core-js
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Imran\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-18T20_29_53_701Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting react20/ from C:\Users\Imran\Desktop\zertomastery\20_react
Done.
PS C:\Users\Imran\Desktop\zertomastery\20_react>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What could cause an error related to npm not being able to find a file? No contents in my node\_modules subfolder. Why is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415958/what-could-cause-an-error-related-to-npm-not-being-able-to-find-a-file-no-conte)